# NOT IN not working in mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this table that represents friendships

```
+--------+--------+
| user_1 | user_2 |
+--------+--------+
| 1      | 5      |
| 2      | 67     |
| 3      | 23     |
| ...    | ...    |
+--------+--------+
```

My goal is to create a procedure that returns friends of friends of a user (that does not include friends).

I started by creating a procedure to return friends for a given user

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getFriends`(IN `myuser` BIGINT(20))
    NO SQL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS friends;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE friends
SELECT user_2
FROM fb_friends
WHERE user_1=myuser;
END
```

This procedure, for user 534477793, creates the following temporary table

```
+------------+
|   user_2   |
+------------+
|  527419864 |
|  580101923 |
|  620972114 |
|  651861323 |
|  662123645 |
|  676185145 |
|  682866129 |
|  718761310 |
|  729611272 |
| 1036862839 |
+------------+
```

Then I created another procedure that calls the first one and return friends of friends

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getFriendsOfFriends`(IN `myuser` BIGINT(20))
BEGIN
-- Creates the table friends
CALL getFriends(myuser);

SELECT DISTINCT(fb.user_2)
FROM fb_friends fb, friends f
-- This works
WHERE fb.user_1 IN (f.user_2)
-- This doesn't
AND fb.user_2 NOT IN (f.user_2);

END
```

And the query returns the following:

```
+------------+
|   user_2   |
+------------+
|  729611272 |
|  527419864 |
|  651861323 |
|  676185145 |
| 1036862839 |
|  502741322 |
|  546744626 |
|  636845886 |
|  652813833 |
|  663713246 |
|  682866129 |
|  781419583 |
|  845134109 |
| 1355751897 |
| 1359286892 |
| 1275961636 |
|  620972114 |
|  509609160 |
|  662123645 |
| 1460283586 |
+------------+
```

So it's clear that the **NOT IN** didn't work since all values from `getFriends` are in the second results set.

I managed to get the results I wanted by doing ugly stuff but still, I'd like to understand what's wrong here. And there's no **NULL** value anywhere by the way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's because `f.user_2` in your `NOT IN` is just a single user, not the entire set. 
The correct way to do it is

```
SELECT DISTINCT(fb.user_2)
FROM fb_friends fb, friends f
WHERE fb.user_1 IN (f.user_2)
AND fb.user_2 NOT IN (SELECT * FROM friends);
```

Note the the first `IN` can be replaced with an `=` operator, because again there's only one element in the `IN` list.

Or you can completely remove the join to make the query consistent (but it will probably regress the performance)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(fb.user_2)
FROM fb_friends fb
WHERE fb.user_1 IN (SELECT * FROM friends)
AND fb.user_2 NOT IN (SELECT * FROM friends);
```

Comment: I'd like to tell you this works but I get an empty set doing one or the other... I really don't get it since friends is really a subset of the query with the first WHERE clause. And I didn't know that IN (f.user_2) returns only one element, thanks for pointing that out my sql is rusty.

Comment: I'm really surprised this doesn't work. I had to create a temporary table to hold the result of the first IN and then use the NOT IN on that table, which is ridiculous.

Comment: That's interesting. I just ran both queries on some sample data, and they worked just fine. May be you forgot to call `getFriends`? Does your query that you posted in the question still work?

Comment: Yes, getFriends get called. If i remove everything from the second procedure except call getFriends(myuser) and then add SELECT * FROM friends it ouputs as it should... This is so esoteric. It should work. There might be a bug from using temporary tables, i don't know..

Answer (score 0):

I thought the problem might be with temporary table and I was right. By executing the query in MySQLWorkbench the following error was ouput:

```
Error Code: 1137. Can't reopen table: 'friends'
```

So I went online to check if there was a limit on the number of times a temporary table can be used in the same query and [in fact there is](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html).

So I might just the temporary table into a permanent one (and drop it every time beforehand) and all will work as expected. *sigh*